signals return error: is not a function at Object.computation
this is my cart service code:
export class ManageCartItemsService {
   cartItems=signal<CartProductModel[]>([]);
   item={} as CartProductModel;
}

and this is my code for showing cart items count in other component:


import { Component, computed, OnInit, Signal } from '@angular/core';
import { ManageCartItemsService } from '../../_services/cartv2/manage-cart-items.service';

export class CartIconComponent implements OnInit{

  cartItemCounter:Signal<number>=computed(()=>this._ManageCartItemsService.cartItems().reduce(
    (acc,item)=>acc+item.quantity,0
  ));
  
  constructor(private _ManageCartItemsService:ManageCartItemsService){}
  
 }



and i get this console error on CartIconComponent:

ERROR TypeError: this._ManageCartItemsService.cartItems is not a function


issue not reproducible stackblitz make sure you import signal from @angular/core

thank you, but that is imported! problem is not from this.

please replicate it on the stackblitz shared and update on the question, to debug the issue.

I feel the problem is "use a variable before declared". You can use inject instead of the constructor to inject the service:_ManageCartItemsService:ManageCartItemsService=inject(ManageCartItemsService)   cartItemCounter:Signal<number>=computed(()=>this._ManageCartItemsService.cartItems().reduce(     (acc,item)=>acc+item.quantity,0   ));   constructor(){} (Apologies for the "ugly" comment but "someone" close the question. See stackblitz
